# APISIX gateway.ingress.enabled=true results in 400 bad request

Tags: apache-apisix

I started using `APISIX`, and everything works fairly smooth out of the box. I managed to get `cert-manager` to work as well.
However, after enabling `gateway.ingress` I started running into `400 Bad Request - Request Header Or Cookie Too Large` errors.

`values.yaml`:

```
gateway:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    className: "apisix"
    annotations: {
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    }
    hosts:
      - host: api.domain.ltd
        paths: [/*]
    tls:
      - secretName: api-domain-ltd-tls
        hosts:
          - api.domain.ltd
```

After some debugging I realize that what's going on is that the `upstream` of the `/*` route created by `apisix-ingress-controller` is using `pass_host: pass` which results in a loop, and the `400 Bad Request` occurs after `n` tries.

At least, that's the theory, since changing it to `pass_host: node` solves the problem, and this is replicable through the `apisix pod`. Solving the problem in the sense that it will return `{"error_msg":"404 Route Not Found"}`.

As a side note, this doesn't occur when you define additional `path` ie `/path` to a different `upstream`. That will resolve fine.

Anyway, what is the recommended way to deal with this situation? Am I supposed to use a different `path`, patch the `upstream`, just let it `400` if there's no specific `path` specified? Or am I missing something entirely?

I would generally ignore it, and let it `400` but it seems relatively prone to (`D`)`DoS` attacks to due the fact you can use it to amplify traffic (`request * nretries`).